# What is a hiking trail consist of stones called?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I am looking for a proper word, which can be used to describe a trail, consisting of small stones.

Sample Sentence: Since the trail has several steep climbs and consist of stones ***(what is the proper word here)***, it is not an easy hike.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean cairns placed as markers or stepping-stones across a creek or up the mountainside? If you could add a photo illustrating the thing you’re talk about, it would help us understand what you mean.

Comment: @tchrist: I have added the image. What is this kind of trail/road called?

Comment: Thanks. Those are much smaller stones, like little pebbles, not the great, big stepping-stones I was imagining you meant. So your picture helps a lot.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, they are not pebbles. Seems like, they were made by crushing rocks and then placed there to make the path a little better.

Comment: If they were placed there and did not arrive naturally, then "gravel" is probably the right answer.  You might also describe the trail as "rocky" though that tends to imply larger sized rocks.

Comment: Since the trail has several steep climbs and has a crushed gravel treadway, it is not an easy hike.

Answer (score 6):

A **gravel** trail

[image: gravel]

[**gravel**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gravel)

> 1  A loose aggregation of small water-worn or pounded stones.
>   1.1 A mixture of gravel with coarse sand, used for paths and roads and as an aggregate.
>   1.2 A stratum or deposit of gravel.

I would say that if it is cobbled, the stones are fixed in place, but in a gravel trail the stones are loose.

Comment: It looks more like a gravel path to me. Trails are not usually gravel but they could be.

Comment: Since the gravel trail has several steep climbs, it is not an easy hike.

Comment: @Lambie yeah in my head trail are 100s of miles long and nobody gravels them

Comment: @WendyG Yes, trails through woods or forests are often bare. However, there are shorter trails in parks and so forth, that could have gravel on t hem.

Comment: @Lambie I went digging and it appears I am wrong Trail "A beaten path through the countryside.

‘country parks with nature trails’
‘easy waymarked trails for the casual walker’" I suppose thinking about I am going on a fairy trail this weekend, i expect it to be 2 miles at most.

Answer (score 1):

If the small stones were not placed there, but developed over time due to erosion and weathering, the word you are looking for is "scree".  However, this is not a very commonly used word for describing trails, and does typically imply a fairly steep slope though this is not technically part of the formal definition.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scree

Comment: As Wikipedia indicates, *talus* is a synonym.  [It's also more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Scree%2Ctalus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CScree%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctalus%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for 'cobbled':

> cobbled
>
> adjective: cobbled
>   (of an area or roadway) paved with cobbles.
>   "a cobbled courtyard"

[Cobbled Trail](https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g189433-d2368798-i117644028-Hiking_Trail_Fira_Oia-Santorini_Cyclades_South_Aegean.html)

This photo of Hiking Trail Fira - Oia is courtesy of TripAdvisor

[Definition of cobble from TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cobble)

> cob·ble   (kŏb′əl)
>
> n.
>   1. A cobblestone.
>
> 2. Geology A rock fragment between 64 and 256 millimeters in diameter, especially one that has been naturally rounded.
> 3. cobbles See cob coal.
>      tr.v. cob·bled, cob·bling, cob·bles
>      To pave with cobblestones.